# update array elements based on its values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i have following array

```
let array = [
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''}
]
```

and when the review is `not_started` for all elements in array, i want to update the status of the first one to `Begin here` and other's to locked. like here

```
let array = [
  {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'},
  {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'},
  {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'},
  {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'}
]
```

When the review for first one is `completed` then update its status to `completed` and second one's status to `Begin here` and others to `locked` like here

```
let array = [
      {review: 'completed', status: 'completed'},
      {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'},
      {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'},
      {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'}
    ]
```

If first two elements review is completed then the array would look like this

```
let array = [
      {review: 'completed', status: 'completed'},
      {review: 'completed', status: 'completed'},
      {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'},
      {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'}
    ]
```

I tried looping over array (`.map`) but can't figure out how to update the status based on review.

How can i achieve this in react?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add JSX where it is utilized?Definitely there is some user action to update the review and status

Comment: There is no difference between react and plain js, since react just uses js map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array = [
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''},
  {review: 'not_started', status: ''}
]
let not_started = true;
array.forEach((item)=>{
  if(item.review!=='not_started'){
    not_started=false;
  }
})
if(not_started){
  array = array.map((item,index)=>{
    if(index==0){
      return {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'}
    }
    else return {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'}
  })
}
/////////////////////second part of the question/////////////////////////////

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i].review==='completed'){
    array[i].status='completed';
    if(array[i+1].review==='completed')
    continue;
    else{
     array[i+1] = {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'};
     i++;
    }
  }
  else {
    array[i]= {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'};
  }
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohith Murali. I tried updating first element's review to completed and its updating first one's status to completed and second ones to Begin here but its not updating the status of other two. do you know why?

Comment: Thanks again but its updating status locked for all elements when review is not_started for all

Comment: All those conditions(parts) are together. I also updated question

Comment: Updated the answer again

Comment: Where you able to sort it out?

Comment: how do i wrap this in react `const`?? getting bunch of errors

Answer (score 0):

```
let all_reviews_not_started = true
let modified_state = []

array.forEach(item => {
  if(item.review !== 'not_started') {
      all_reviews_not_started = false
    }
})

if(all_reviews_not_started) {
  modified_state = array.map((item, i) => {
    if(i == 0) return {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin Here'}
    else {review: 'not_started', status: 'locked'}
  })
} else {
  modified_state = [...array]
  array.forEach((item, i) => {
    if(item.review == 'completed' && modified_state[i+1].status == 'locked'){
     modified_state[i].status = 'completed'
     modified_state[i+1] = {review: 'not_started', status: 'Begin here'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let STATUS_BEGIN = 'Begin here';
 let STATUS_LOCKED = 'locked';
 let STATUS_COMPLETE = 'completed';
 let STATUS_NOT_STARTED = 'not_started';

    function updateStatus(array) {
        var count = 0;
        array.forEach(function(e, i) {
            if (e.review == STATUS_NOT_STARTED && e.status != STATUS_BEGIN) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (e.review == STATUS_COMPLETE && e.status != STATUS_COMPLETE) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (e.review == STATUS_NOT_STARTED && count == 1) {

                e.status = STATUS_BEGIN;


            } else if (e.review == STATUS_COMPLETE && count == 1) {
                e.status = STATUS_COMPLETE;
                if (array[i + 1]) array[i + 1].status = STATUS_BEGIN;

            } else if (e.status != STATUS_BEGIN && e.status != STATUS_COMPLETE) {
                e.status = STATUS_LOCKED;
            }

        })
        return array;

    }

    let array = [{
            review: STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
            status: ''
        },
        {
            review: STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
            status: ''
        },
        {
            review: STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
            status: ''
        },
        {
            review: STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
            status: ''
        }
    ]

    updateStatus(array);
```